# Listing a list inside the list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

I have list of book titles and I have to list chapters like this.

```
Title 1 
       Chapter1
       Chapter2
       Chapter3
       Chapter4
Title 2 
       Chapter1
       Chapter2
```

So, I have list inside a list. I can get list of books (and titles) but when i reference their chapters i get nothing. well, how can I do that?

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Text) %>
            </th>
        </tr>

        <% foreach (var chapters in item.Chapter){%>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%=Html.Encode(chapters.Number)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%=Html.Encode(chapters.Text)%>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>    

    <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have any chapters contained in your `item.Chapter` property. Can you check that they do exist- ie you are adding them somewhere in your logic. A breakpoint in the view would be one way of confirming this.

Answer (score 0):

Logic written in the code is correct. Check whether the entries are there in the sub-list